# Probability of selecting a jury

Tags: probability, permutations, problem-solving, decision-trees

Does anyone know how to find the probability of selecting a jury of $12$ people ($6$ men and $6$ women) out of an initial group of $18$ people ($6$ men and $12$ women)?

With my knowledge of probability, the only way I can think to solve this is by drawing a big tree diagram with $12$ events. Is there a quicker way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with binomial coefficients?

Answer (score 5):

There are $\binom{6}{6}=1$ ways to choose $6$ men, and $\binom{12}{6}=924$ ways to choose the $6$ women. Therefore, there are $\binom{6}{6}\cdot\binom{12}{6}=924$ ways to pick $12$ jurors so that $6$ are women and $6$ are men. In total, there are $\binom{18}{12}=18564$ ways to choose $12$ jurors from $18$ people. Hence, the desired probability is

$$
\frac{924}{18564}\approx 4.98\%.
$$

Comment: Jess, since it sounds like you have a fairly elementary knowledge of concepts in probability, it helps to know that the notation ${n}\choose{k}$ is the binomial coefficient, said as $n$ choose $k$ or the how many ways to choose k objects from a total of $n$. 

The formula for calculating the binomial coefficient by hand is: 

$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$